# Symfony 5 Mailer Recipient more than one adress does not working

Tags: php, symfony

In the Symfony Documentation there is this entry:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#email-addresses

...you can pass multiple addresses to each method:

```
$toAddresses = ['foo@example.com', new Address('bar@example.com')];
$email = (new Email())
    ->to(...$toAddresses)
    ->cc('cc1@example.com', 'cc2@example.com')

    // ...
```

;

So this is my array:

```
$recipients = [
    'test1@test.de',
    'test2@test.de'
];
```

And when I try to send this like this:

```
$recipients = [
    'test1@test.de',
    'test2@test.de'
];
$email->to($recipients);
```

I got an error:

```
An address can be an instance of Address or a string ("array") given).
```

What is wrong here? Ok - Let's try to send it with a string:

When I try to send it like this:

```
$recipients = "test1@test.de,test2@test.de";
$email->to($recipients);
```

I got another error:

> Email "test1@test.de,test2@test.de" does not comply with addr-spec of
> RFC 2822.

Can anyone explain how to send emails with the symfony mailer to more than one `->to()` Address?

Comment: From your first code block posted, try `$email->to(...$recipients);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) your array. `to()` method accepts multiple parameters and each parameter must be *string* or an instance of *Address*

So, in your code, you need to add `...` before `$recipients` to unpack the array.

```
$recipients = [
    'test1@test.de',
    'test2@test.de'
];

$email->to(...$recipients);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this;

```
// Record(s) from database using entityManager.
$users = $em-> ....;
$recipients = array_map(function ($user) {
    return new Address($user->getEmail(), $user->getFirstname());
}, $users);

$email->to(...$recipients);
```

Comment: What is "this"? `$em-> ...` does not look like valid PHP code to me

Comment: $entityManager, in case you're trying to retrieve record(s) from database.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. Why is that relevant to resolve the problem?